# HELP - The book that illuminates the learnings/ideas/message that Mahabharata and Ramayana seek to portray through their stories and characters

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana

I want to read Mahabharata and Ramayana but I also want to know the underlying messages or learning that they seek to illustrate so Is there any book which illuminates the learnings and ideas of Mahabharata and Ramayana which they seek to pass on through their stories and characters. 
Please suggest. I am tired of finding anything conclusive. 
Happy New Year!